# Kotlin incompatible when creating Micronaut command line applications

Tags: kotlin, command-line, micronaut

Whenever I attempt to create a command line app with Micronaut and Kotlin using:

`mn create-cli-app cli2 --features kotlin`

I get the following warning:

`| Warning The following features are incompatible with other feature selections and have been removed from the project
| kotlin`

The generated project has fallen back to Java, which is very graceful.

Is this a "bug" or current expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For selecting the language (java, groovy or kotlin) it is better to use the `--lang` flag instead of `--features`.
Doing:

```
$ mn create-cli-app mycli --lang=kotlin
| Generating Kotlin project...
| Application created at /tmp/mycli
```

Works as expected.